# can nymous be used as an antonym of anonymous

Tags: antonyms, auto-antonyms

What should I use as an antonym of anonymous ? is `nymous` a correct antonym of anonymous ?

Comment: If you're being literal, maybe "nominate"? Otherwise, I would use "name".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"[onymous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/onymous)" means "having a name" and is a back-formation from "anonymous". This means the word anonymous existed first in English, and then from there "onymous" was created.

etymonline tells us that "[anonymous](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=anonymous&searchmode=none)" is

> from Greek anonymos "without a name," from an- "without" + onyma, Æolic dialectal form of onoma "name"

and "[onymous](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=onymous&searchmode=none)"

> 1775, coined to provide an opposite to anonymous.

[Google Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=onymous,%20anonymous&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,onymous;,c0;.t1;,anonymous;,c0) shows that this word is not in common usage ("anonymous" included for comparison).

Comment: So the word "onymous" may be used `experimentally` but not conventional ?

Comment: In a way. Many people wouldn't know what you mean or would think you are making up the word if you used "onymous".That means it is likely to distract from your meaning. It is generally advisable to use clear, common language

Answer (score 5):

The opposite of *anonymous* is either *named* or *known*, depending on the context.